# Update data of AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a simple AngularJS script to load data from a socket.io event and then add it to the ng template, this is my JS:

```
// Socket.io logic:
var messages = [];
socket.on("chat message", function(message){
    messages.push(message); //message = {username: String, text: String}
});

// AngularJS logic:
var app = angular.module("chat", []);
app.controller("MessagesCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.messages = messages;    
})
```

Now I'd like to understand how to update my ng template when a new message is added to my messages[]...

This is an example fiddle with one attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/v8v67ohn/1/
As you can see, clicking the button nothing happens...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-click` instead of setting a new MessagesCtrl in a jQuery event handler.

You can do this like this:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MessagesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [{username: "foo", text: "hi"}, {username: "bar",text: "hey"}, {username: "foo",text: "LOL"}]    

    $scope.onClick = function() {
        $scope.messages = [{username: "foo", text: "hi"}, {username: "bar",text: "hey"}, {username: "foo",text: "LOL"}, {username: "new one", text: "Hi all, I'm new here"}]
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MessagesCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="message.html">
        <b>{{message.username}}</b>: {{message.text}}
    </script>        
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-include="'message.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="click" ng-click="onClick()">aaaa</button>
</body>
```

See the [jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v8v67ohn/2/)

Comment: Thanks! What if I wan to call "onClick" on the socket.io event?

Comment: You have to notify angularjs that you changed the messages array. Therefore put the socket code block in your controller and make an $apply call like this: `$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.messages.push(message); });`
More information about $apply: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 1):

Use on button click ng-click="newData()" function

```
<button id="click" ng-click="newData()">aaaa</button>
```

And Set in your controler

```
$scope.newData=function(){


 $scope.messages = [{username: "foo", text: "hi"}, {username: "bar",text: "hey"}, {username: "foo",text: "LOL"}, {username: "new one", text: "Hi all, I'm new here"}]
}
```